# Quick Calculation for Grobner Basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am currently using Buchberger's Algorithm to calculate a Grober basis for the ideal $(tx_1^2x_2,tx_2x_4,tx_3x_4x_5,x_1x_3^2-tx_1x_3^2,x_2x_4-tx_2x_4,x_2^3x_5-tx_2^3x_5)$ and it's taking a while going step-by-step; is there an online calculator that could spit out the Grobner Basis for me? Also, the monomial order is lexicographic with $t>x_1>x_2>...$

Comment: Are you familiar with [Macauley2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/)?

Comment: Will that output the right Grobner basis? And does it show steps?